# Building a JSON object with an array as a value

Tags: go

I need to send an Array inside a JSON object with the structure:

```
{"extent":[-76.0624694824, 36.8856620774, -75.9800720215,36.9449529607]}
```

How would I do this? I can't use the typical:

```
var jsonprep string = `{"extent":` + []float32{-76.0624694824, 36.8856620774, -75.9800720215, 36.9449529607} + `}`
var jsonStr = []byte(jsonprep)
```

because of the type mismatch. I am trying to send this to a server that expects it to be an array as I get the error,

```
The request content was malformed:
Expected List as JsArray, but got "[-76.0624694824, 36.8856620774, -75.9800720215,36.9449529607]"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are expecting that the array will change at some point, consider using the encoding/json package

Then you can create a struct prototype of your JSON object, then use json.Marshal() to serialize it into a []byte representation of the JSON object for transfer (whether by stdio, tcp, whatever).

e.g.

```
type ExampleJSON struct {
    Extent []float32 `json:"extent"`
}

func main(){
    var ex := &ExampleJSON{
        []float32{-76.0624694824, 36.8856620774, -75.9800720215, 36.9449529607}
    }
    jsonBytes, err := json.Marshal(ex)
    if err != nil {
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I was overthinking it. The answer was:

```
var jsonprep string = `{"extent":[-76.0624694824, 36.8856620774, -75.9800720215, 36.9449529607]}`
```

Comment: this isn't valid. Please wrap those numbers in square brackets ([]). Also, while you can statically write out the strings, you should look into using the encoding/json package for this stuff.

Comment: I was using it from r.PostFormValue("extent") so I just used those numbers as a stand in. In reality I used  var jsonprep string = `{"extent":` + r.PostFormValue("extent") + `}`